# Getting innerHTML of a node excluding a specific descendant node

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

Let's say you want to get the innerHTML of node A, but you want to exclude node B, a text node that is a descendant of Node A. You have a reference to node B stored in a variable, and you do not want to remove node B from the page. You also do not know the other contents in node A beforehand, so using regular expressions to wipe out the text from the text node could lead to unintended consequences (if the same text is present elsewhere). Is there a way to do this without modifying the page, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You could clone the `A` node, remove the `B` node from it, thus get its innerHTML

```
var A_clone = A.cloneNode();
A_clone.removeChild(B);  
/* B has to be evaluated from the cloned node or - if previously
 * evaluated - it will be a reference of the original A node 
 */

console.log(A_clone.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Will this also work if you instead do `var newA = document.createElement('div'); newA.innerHTML = A.innerHTML; newA.removeChild(B);`??

Comment: Hmmm, just tried it and seems like it won't. Guessing because it's now a different node.

Comment: doing so you're losing the original reference of node `B`

Comment: probably the reference to B node has to be created on the cloned node and not on the original node. How do you get it right now?

Comment: Ahh ok yeah, that should do it, and you need to pass `true` to `cloneNode()` so that is also clones descendants of the receiver node

Comment: yeah the `B` was referenced from the original `A`

Comment: Updated my answer to be more accurate

Answer (score 0):

It won't be fast but you can:

- Clone the outer node
- Descend to the inner node of the clone (using a lookup function of some sort) and remove it
- store the innerHTML of the cloned node
- Discard the cloned node
- return the stored innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

you also could use the [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) object, serialize a and b, finally replace the match of b in a with ""